# string must match two values in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My question is probably ridiculous but I've not found any comprehensive info about what I want to code in JavaScript.

My first idea was to detect if the browser uses the Blink engine by detecting if the user agent of the web browser is containing these strings:"`WebKit/537.36`" and "`Chrome`". This is only for information purpose, not for rendering.

So, is this possible to create a regular expression than will force the string to match **both expressions** using only **one** `match` or `test` declaration?

Instead of using this:

```
navigator.userAgent.match("WebKit\/537\.36") && navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome"); // return true if Blink
```

Thanks for future answers.

Comment: You could do it with one big regular expression, but I'd far rather read your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lookahead here to force 2 conditions in same regex:

```
return /(?=.*?WebKit\/537\.36)(?=.*?Chrome)/i.test( navigator.userAgent );
```